# Frequency of most frequent number in a string

Tags: python, text-processing

Let's suppose that I have a string like that:

```
sentence = 'I am 6,571.5 14 a 14 data 1,a211 43.2 scientist 1he3'
```

I want to have as an output the frequency of the most frequent number in the string.

At the string above this is `2` which corresponds to the number `14` which is the most frequent number in the string.

When I say number I mean something which consists only of digits and `,` or `.` and it is delimited by whitespaces.

Hence, at the string above the only numbers are: `6,571.5`, `14`, `14`, `43.2`.

(Keep in mind that different countries use the `,` and `.` in the opposite way for decimals and thousands so I want to take into account all these possible cases)

How can I efficiently do this?

*P.S.*

*It is funny to discover that in Python there is no (very) quick way to test if a word is a number (including integers and floats of different conventions about `,` and `.`).*

Comment: Please add any relevant code to your question. If you are looking for an optimization to existing code (rather than fixing an issue), I'd recommend [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where this might be a more on topic question. Be sure to look at [what questions are on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for their site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

pattern = '\s*?\d+[\,\.]\d+[\,\.]\d+\s*?|\s*?\d+[\,\.]\d+\s*?|\s[0-9]+\s'
sentence = 'I am 6,571.5 14 a 14 data 1,a211 43.2 scientist 1he3'
[(_ , freq)] = Counter(re.findall(pattern, sentence)).most_common(1)
print(freq)

# output: 2
```

or you can use:

```
def simple(w):
    if w.isalpha():
        return False

    if w.isnumeric():
        return True

    if w.count('.') > 1 or w.count(',') > 1:
        return False

    if w.startswith('.') or w.startswith(','):
        return False

    if w.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').isnumeric():
        return True

    return False

[(_ , freq)] = Counter([w for w in sentence.split() if simple(w)]).most_common(1)
print(freq)

# output: 2
```

but the second solution is ~ 2 times slower

Comment: Hey, the second one looks good too. By the way, I thought that you said that first one was 2 times slower; not the second one? Personally, I tested the second one too at my big dataset but only with the last if condition because it is sufficient for me and it was two times faster than the first one.